# How do I access textual information about an enemy?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

The game says that each Eidolon has specific ways to defeat it. Also, in enemy information screens, there seems to be an area where text is supposed to be displayed but I can't see anything there. I tried this on multiple enemies (even used Libra several times on them) and I have checkmarks next to their names in the datalog but there doesn't seem to be anything.

Is there supposed to be additional information in the form of text or am I supposed to find it by trial and error?

[image: My Odin information screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's text supposed to be there. Here's what Odin's entry looks like for me:

[image: Odin's Datalog Entry]

I've taken the screenshot from the current Steam version of the game using 1280x720 with default settings and English language in windowed mode.

As to ways to "defeat" Eidolons: When the fight start, you should see a help/hint line on the top of the screen that will tell you what to do; you don't have to use *Libra* for this nor do you have to read the Datalog entry (which you can't at those points anyway).

The checkmarks in Datalog entries just show you the entries you've read (or at least opened) before.

---

**Edit:** [According to Steam Community the missing text might be related to the screen resolution you've picked.](http://steamcommunity.com/app/292120/discussions/0/619573787341145379/) This is obviously a bug. Have you tried playing using a different resolution (probably one with a different aspect ratio)?